# Remix - Error: Cannot initialize 'routeModules'

Tags: remix.run

I have the following code in a route file:

```
import { Success } from '@web/components/Success'

export { meta } from '@web/utils/meta'
export { loadPageContent as loader } from '@web/utils/loadContent'

export default Success
```

I want to insert a path into the loader like so:

```
import { Success } from '@web/components/Success'
import { loadPageContentWithPath } from '@web/utils/loadContent'

export { meta } from '@web/utils/meta'
export const loader = loadPageContentWithPath('some-path')

export default Success
```

However, this generates the error message on screen:

> Error: Cannot initialize 'routeModules'. This normally occurs when you have server code in your client modules.

Here are the loader functions:

```
export const loadPageContent = async ({ params, request }) => {
  const { pathname } = new URL(request.url)
  ...

  return fetchContent()
}

export const loadPageContentWithPath = (path) => async ({ params, request }) => {
  const { pathname } = new URL(request.url)
  ...

  return fetchContent(path)
```

}

Comment: In the DevTools console, what is the error message you see before the "cannot initialize" error? That is typically the root cause.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined` which relates to `process.env.GQL_URL` and is in the file that contains both loader functions. But why does this not happen when I use just the first code block in the question above - in both code blocks I am importing this file?

Comment: `loadPageContentWithPath` is a side-effect, so Remix can't tree-shake it out of the client bundle. The simplest way around it is to name your loader function file with the .server suffix (utils/loadContent.server.js). This way Remix knows not to bundle those functions in the client.

Comment: Thank you. I had assumed that this was the case and tried the file renaming but with no luck.